# Cisco IOS limit bandwidth to domain (wildcard)

Tags: cisco-ios, bandwidth

I'm fairly new to Cisco IOS configuration. I have an 800-series router and, long story short, I'd like to limit the incoming and outgoing bandwidth allocated to some iCloud servers to prevent transmissions to/from iCloud photos from saturating our network.

I'm just flummoxed as how to approach the problem—especially having only a domain name to match on and not IP addresses or ports.

Comment: You have no control over incoming traffic. You can drop it after you receive it, but you cannot prevent it from arriving and using the inbound bandwidth. QoS can queue and police outbound traffic, but QoS is a very large and complicated topic. If Cisco NBAR can Identify the traffic, you don't necessarily need to know addresses to do this.

Comment: If the connection is TCP, which it likely is, there are QoS setting to delay the packets (read: "mess with it") to the point it will slow the inbound stream. It's not as clean as outbound, but falls in the realm of possible.

Comment: @RonMaupin re: incoming packets — Brain fart as my frustration mounted and I hastily threw this question up here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Traffic shaping is how you would do the limiting.  This will require classifying traffic to be shaped (limited).  I did find a doc, [TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944), but [NBAR](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/qos_nbar/configuration/15-mt/qos-nbar-15-mt-book/clsfy-traffic-nbar.html) may be a better way to match/classify the iCloud photo sharing.  Like you said, if you can determine a particular destination domain then [NBAR can match that way](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/qos_nbar/configuration/15-mt/qos-nbar-15-mt-book/clsfy-traffic-nbar.html#GUID-282B8171-F2C0-4083-B0B7-E723DB4F725C).

Comment: Right, so I saw that document. But I don't want to clamp down on port 443 entirely, just uploads to iCloud basically. I'll give NBAR a shot.

Comment: @samh  Check out [NBAR2](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/qos_nbar/prot_lib/config_library/pp1300/nbar-prot-pack1300/nbar-prot-a1200.html) Protocol Pack.